# Help identify early 90s Chro-Moly MTB

Tags: mountain-bike, frames, vintage, steel

I have this Chro-Moly bike I bought in the early 90s in Chile branded as Oxford, but I believe the frame is an import. One mechanic said it is japanese, another that it's italian. The rear part of this frame is very BMX-style, with the rear higher tubes being a fork (same shape as the front fork) instead of a triangle; and the rear end where it meets the rear hub, the tubes turn instead of joining two separate pieces.

Thanks in advance!

PS: I've resto-modded this bike with a Shimano Cues 1x11 transmission, a more modern wheelset, and V-Brakes, while keeping my legendary Shimano DX BMX pedals. It originally came with Shimano Acera-X transmission and hubs, and Shimano Cantilever brakes.

[image: Bike frame in full view]

[image: frame detail]

[[image: frame detail][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iLV5N.jpg)

[[image: frame detail][4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s0uhy.jpg)

[[image: frame detail][5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XaNiP.jpg)

[image: stem detail]

Comment: Welcome. You've provided decent photos and info but if you want to max your chances then there a few extra hints listed here https://bicycles.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1337/how-do-i-ask-a-good-id-my-bike-question

Comment: Are you sure it’s not Titanium ? Looks really shiny for a 35 year old steel frame even if clearcoated?

Comment: I wish, Warren! But it's not as light as Ti and it certainly didn't cost that much. I've cleaned it several times with different treatments since buying it back from the second owner, and recently I finish it off with furniture polish after cleaning every week.

Thanks pateksan, I'll include more photos and details.

Comment: Thanks Noise, that makes sense. The rear terminals are different, mine is probably even older. But what you say makes sense, back then [Oxford] (https://www.oxfordstore.cl/) built some models in-house and imported frames for others. Now they custom import some and sell imported brands as well. It does ride nice and stiff, and brings back lots of memories so it's a treat to have it refurbished.

Answer (score 5):

https://i.ytimg.com/vi/XBgB9kSAkOw/maxresdefault.jpg

The above image shows a bike that is not your bike but has the same frame features as yours. It was a fairly common arrangement. You have got a fairly standard early 90s tig-welded cromo frame and it will probably be great to ride but it will have been mass produced in the far east for this Oxford company and there are no great special mysteries about its origins or design, no pirate treasure map hidden in the downtube. it’s using features that were common in the market at that time.

Nice to see you’re keeping it clean.

Ps

The finish could be a metal plating eg nickel, which is a special finish and is cool. The furniture wax or car wax polish will keep it looking good.

Answer (score 2):

There are several ["Oxford Stores"](https://www.oxfordstore.cl/sucursales/) in Chile that sell [Oxford branded bicycles](https://www.oxfordstore.cl/).
Copilot says they have been around since 1956 and refers to their [facebook page](https://www.facebook.com/Oxford.Chile/) as the source.

My guess is that in the early 90s they sold enough bicycles to contract with makers in China to create an Oxford brand bicycle with the model name Aquamarine.
But, maybe they make their own bicycles.

I did my best to research the Oxford Stores site but my Spanish is poor. Contacting them might provide some information.